# Create a type with the keys from a Map?

Tags: typescript, maps

How can I create a type with the keys from a Map?

```
export const languageOptionsMap = new Map<string, ILanguageOption>([
    [
        'cs',
        {
            value: 'cs',
            order: 1,
            text: 'Česky',
        },
    ],
    [
        'en',
        {
            value: 'en',
            order: 2,
            text: 'English',
        },
    ],
]);
```

I want to generate the type LanguageCode without having to repeat the keys of the map as I do below:

```
export type LanguageCode = 'cs' | 'en';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After passing the data to the map we can't extract the type information. If we put the data in a separate variable and use a `const` assertion (in 3.4) to make sure typescript keeps string literal types we can extract the type information from there:

```
const data = [
    [
        'cs',
        {
            value: 'cs',
            order: 1,
            text: 'Česky',
        },
    ],
    [
        'en',
        {
            value: 'en',
            order: 2,
            text: 'English',
        },
    ],
] as const
export const languageOptionsMap = new Map<string, ILanguageOption>(data);
export type LanguageCode = typeof data[number][0]
```

Comment: Whenever I see `Map<string, XXX>` I wonder why someone isn't using a plain object type.  In this case, the constraint that `languageOptionsMap.get(key).value === key` cannot be represented with the `Map` interface, but could be expressed as a mapped type like `const asLanguageOptions = <T extends { [K in keyof T]: ILanguageOption & { value: K } }>(t: T) => t;`.  ‍♂️

Comment: @jcalz Fully agreed about the plain object, much simpler IMO. And indeed the assumption that `languageOptionsMap.get(key).value === key` is unchecked. But hey I just provide the  for the  :)